# How to copy the column id from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm stuck with this since last week. I have two tables, where the `id` column of `CustomerTbl` correlates with `CustomerID` column of `PurchaseTbl`:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to duplicate the data of the table from itself, but copy the newly generated id of `CustomerTbl` to `PurchaseTbl's` `CustomerID`

[image]

Just like from the screenshots above. Glad for any help :)

Comment: `just like from the image above` SQL Server doesn't generate output which looks like this.  Are these Excel dumps based on an actual SQL query?

Comment: nope..i just make an example of it..from what i'm trying to achieve..

Comment: So you just want to copy PurchaseTbl into itself, but make all the customerID 1s into 4s, 2s into 5s etc?

Comment: @LordBaconPants something like that but the id in custormerTbl is autogenerated..

Comment: Copy the data in `CustomerTbl` by using a `insert ... select ...` with an [`output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to capture both the old and new `id` values. Then use those values in another `insert ... select ...` to create a copy of the rows in the `PurchaseTbl`. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: So the new rows that you are adding to CustomerTbl; how do they relate to the rows you want to add to PurchaseTbl? I get that PurchaseTbl.CustomerID is a foreign key, but I don't understand what you are asking for in an answer. Are you adding in the customers first? Do you have some sort of mapping? How do we know what rows to duplicate from PurchaseTbl to which new customer entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `OUTPUT` clause to access to the new ID. But to access to both OLD ID and NEW ID, you will need to use `MERGE` statement. `INSERT` statement does not allow you to access to the source old id.

first you need somewhere to store the old and new id, a mapping table. You may use table variable or temp table

```
declare @out table
(
    old_id  int,
    new_id  int
)
```

then the merge statement with output clause

```
merge 
        #CustomerTbl as t
using
(
        select  id, name
        from    CustomerTbl
) as s
on      1 = 2                       -- force it to `false`, not matched
when    not matched then
        insert (name)
        values (name)
output                              -- the output clause
        s.id,                       -- old_id
        inserted.id                 -- new_id
into    @out (old_id, new_id);
```

after that you just use the @out to join back using old_id to obtain the new_id for the PurchaseTbl

```
insert into PurchaseTbl (CustomerID, Item, Price)
select  o.new_id, p.Item, p.Price
from    @out o
        inner join PurchaseTbl p    on  o.old_id    = p.CustomerID
```

Comment: wooow..tnx a bunch mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your end game is, but one way you could solve this is this:

```
INSERT INTO purchaseTbl ( customerid ,
                      item ,
                      price )
        SELECT customerid + 3 ,
               item ,
               price
        FROM   purchaseTbl;
```